# Run in jmeter HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter

I want to do this:
1- Run 10 query the same time, in one component and after pass for 10 HTTP Request, one by one 
How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear and needs to be improved in order than anybody can help you.  See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Thread Group to your Test Plan and set "Number of Threads" to `10`

   [image: JMeter Thread Group 10]
2. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) which you want to be executed simultaneously
3. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to `10`

   [image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer]

   The request will be executed by 10 threads at exactly the same time
4. Add [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) to the Thread Group
5. Put the request which you want to be executed one by one as a child of the Critical Section Controller

Test outline and demo:

[image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer and Parallel Controller]